# Show about cyclic group theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show by a counterexample that the following "converse" of Theorem(A subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic) is not a theorem : "If a group G is such that every proper subgroup is cyclic, then G is cyclic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$.  Then $C_2\times C_2\cong \{(1,1),(1,x),(x,1),(x,x)\}$ with component-wise multiplication where $x^2=1$ is a counterexample to the converse.  To see this, we note that none of the elements generate the group.  The order is 4, so that the proper subgroups are $\{(1,1)\}$, $\{(1,1),(1,x)\}$, $\{(1,1), (x,1)\}$, and $\{(1,1),(x,x)\}$, all of which are cyclic subgroups.

Comment: This is the simplest and smallest counterexample. It is the Klein 4-group, usually denoted $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ or $V$ (for *Vierergruppe*).

Answer (score 1):

Consider Prüfer $p$-group $C(p^\infty)$ obtained by injecting $C(p^n)$ inside $C(p^{n+1})$ and taking a union $\bigcup\limits_{n\geqslant 1}C(p^n)$. This is also the $p$-primary part of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$, that is, the set of cosets of the form $kp^{-n}+\Bbb Z$. The quaternion group $Q_8$ is also a noncyclic group (since it is not abelian) all whose subgroups are cyclic.